# cannot find item error

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary

my code has two errors that I cannot find or understand and was hoping someone could give me some input on how to fix this. it says for line 118 and 125 for my delete function that the symbol 'item' cannot be found. I thought i made it clear in my code what item was. I will post my code below and hopefully someone can help.

```
  8  public class Dictionary implements DictionaryInterface {
  9 
 10    // private inner Node class
 11    private class Node {
 12       String  key;
 13       String value;
 14       Node left;
 15       Node right;
 16       Node next;
 17 
 18       Node(String k, String v) {
 19          key = k;
 20          value = v;
 21          left = null;
 22          right = null;
 23          next = null;
 24       }
 25    }
 26 
 27    //Fields for the IntegerList class
 28    private Node root;    // reference to the head Node in list 
 29    private int numItems; // number of items in this IntegerList  
 30 
 31    //Dictionary()
 32    //constructor for the Dictionary class
 33    public Dictionary() {
 34       root = null;
 35       numItems = 0;
 36    }
 37 
38    // find key
 39    // returns a reference to the Node containing key k in the subtree rooted at 
 40    // R or Null if no such Node exists
 41    private Node findKey (String key){
 42       Node N = root;
 43         while (N != null){
 44            if(key.equals(N.key))
 45                break;
 46             N = N.next;
 47         }
 48    }
 49 
 50    // ADT operations ---------------------------------------------
 51 
 52    // isEmpty()
 53    // pre: none
 54    // post: returns true if this Dictionary is empty, false otherwise 
 55    public boolean isEmpty() {
 56       return (numItems == 0);
 57    }
 58 
 59    // size()
 60    // pre: none
 61    // post: returns the number of elements in this Dictionary 
 62    public int size() {
 63       return numItems;
 64    }
65 
 66    // lookup(String key)
 67    // get()
 68    // pre: 1<= key <= size()
 69    // post: returns item at position key in this Dictionary 
 70    public String lookup(String key){
 71         Node N = root;
 72            while( N != null){
 73               if(key.equals(N.key))
 74                 break;
 75                N = N.next;
 76            }
 77            if( N != null){
 78              return N.value;
 79            }else{
 80               return null;
 81                 }
 82    }
 83 
 84 
85    // insert(String key, String value)
 86    // inserts new (key, value) pair into this Dictionary
 87    // pre: key k does not exist in this Dictionary, i.e lookup(k) == UNDEFINED 
 88    // post: !isEmpty(), size() is increased by one 
 89    public void insert(String k, String v) throws KeyCollisionException{
 90        // Node N = root;
 91          if (lookup(k) != null){
 92            throw new KeyCollisionException("cannot insert duplicate keys");
 93           }
 94       if (numItems== 0) {
 95          root = new Node(k,v);
 96       }else{
 97          Node N = new Node(k,v);
 98           N=N.next;
 99       }
100          Node P = null;  //N
101          Node C = P.next;
102          P.next = new Node (k, v);
103          P = P.next;
104          P.next = C;
105 
106      numItems++;
107 
108    }
109 
110    // delete(String key)
111    // pre: key k currently exists in this Dictionary, i.e. lookup(k)!= UNDEFINED
112    // post: size() is decreased by one 
113    public void delete(String k) throws KeyNotFoundException{
114       Node N = root;
115       if (lookup (k) == null){
116           throw new KeyNotFoundException("cannot delete non-existent key");
117       }
118       if (k.compareTo(N.item)==0) {
119           Node P = root;
120           root = root.next;
121           P.next = root;
122           numItems--;
123        }else{
124           while(N !=null && N.next !=null){
125             if (k.compareTo(N.next.item)==0){
126                 Node P =  N;
127                 Node C = P.next;
128                 P.next = C.next;
129                 N=P;
130             }
131            N=N.next;
132        }
133       numItems--;
134      }
135    }
136 
137    // makeEmpty()
138    // pre: none
139    // post: isEmpty()
140    public void makeEmpty(){
141       root = null; // root = 0;
142       numItems = 0;
143    }
```

Comment: There's no attribute `Item` in `Node`.

Comment: Where is the item attribute in your Node class?

Comment: class `Node` does not contain a member called `item`

Comment: so once I create String item would it make sense to have item = k??

Comment: @jpw Based on the description of the method, I think it's supposed to be comparing k to `key`, not `value`.

Comment: @McLovin Yeah, guess I misread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you want to be comparing `k` to the `N.key`, but you are comparing it to `N.item`, which does not exist. Change `item` to `key` on both of the lines.